# Customise user and account names in signature ceremony

Tags: docusignapi

I'm providing a service for many different clients.

I'm using the DocuSign APIs.

I'd like to customise the user name and the account name displayed at the top left of the signature ceremony web page (the part surrounded with a red line in the screenshot below)

[image: change user and account names]

It looks like it needs a new account each time the account name needs to be changed and a new user each time the user name needs to be changed.

Is it possible to do this without creating new account and new user, and how can I do this via the API?

I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: You can get additional accounts and/or user ids depending on your use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sender Account Name/User Name cannot be changed per envelope. Once they are set during account creation they will be applied to all the envelopes sent from the account.

If your integration is supporting multiple clients, then you will probably have to authenticate differently. DocuSign supports various authentication mechanisms. Consider using [oAuth](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_auth_code.html) or [SOBO](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/sobo.html) based on your application needs.